# Reuse google app engine app for new instance

Tags: google-app-engine

My website is built by app engine java SDK on Master/Slave datastore (it is read-only now.) I want to rebuild it with other type SDK (eg. Java or python) and use the same app (because I hope the url is the same.) I have found that Master/Slave datastore app could be migrated to HRD app. Is that means I could migrate my app to HRD version and access it by old url ? And, after I migrate my app, could I upload a new version website and it also be accessed with old url ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that should all work.  To protect your old code, deploy to a new version of your application, and you will be able to switch back if anything is wrong with the new upload.  To prevent almost all possible problems, practice first with a different application id.  You can also use the AppEngine console to copy all your data from one application to another (not sure what it does about the Master/Slave though).

Comment: Hi Martin, I have tried to migrate my old app to new app. First I deployed full website to new app and then used migration tool to migrate old app to new app. But it takes a long time in "sync" phase. Did you have met similar problem ??? Thanks ~

Comment: I've not met a similar problem but if you're copying lots of data that could certainly be very slow.  I suggest you try multiple methods for measuring the rate at which data appears to be transferring, because statistics often lag hours or days behind reality.  Remember that even HRD is limited to approximately 1 write per entity group per second.

Comment: Actually, there are not many data in my website ... (https://sailplanetw-website.appspot.com/index.php?page=index&lang=en ) The total size is only 75 MB ...

Comment: "All things are difficult before they are easy".  Very appropriate :-)

Answer (score 0):

This is covered here:

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/adminconsole/migration?hl=en

The alias process referenced in this document is how appengine intercepts traffic from the old appspot id and instead serves from the new app.

You can also copy the data from the old appid to the new one before cutting over which should allow you to test there are no oddities as a result of the M/S to HRD migration.

Adding a new version to an app using M/S will not cause it to use HRD.  The datastore type is an application-level association, not per-version.